# Is there a way to "listen" to image taken events in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm new to React-Native and I couldn't find any clear answer to this online.

I would like to be able to detect a photo/video was taken with the **native mobile camera**, not a customized camera component. needless to say, would love that to work on both ios and android.

Comment: You want to listen to when another app takes a photo?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, the native camera app. if it's not possible directly then maybe check the directory for added file?

Comment: You can get access on iOS to the photo album but I don't think there is a listener that will notify you when the photos have been changed. You would have to continually request all the items in there, keep a record of them and track the changes. This may go against Apple's policies. Also, you would have to write a native module to do this as I do not think that anything like this currently exists.

Comment: "taken with the native mobile camera app" -- there are well over 20,000 Android device models. These ship with hundreds of different "native mobile camera apps". There is no requirement for any of them to save images in a location that your app can access.

Comment: OK, good to know. By the way, I know it is possible and pretty simple to do in native android. Was just wondering if its possible also with react-native.

Comment: @mallocthePD How do you know that it is possible natively on Android? Can you use that code natively in your own module?

Comment: It is possible with react-native outside-the-box with the help of native code. Assuming it is possible to implement the functionality with native code.